# QGIS buffer by percentage plugin error

Tags: qgis, postgis

The python buffer by percentage plugin produces error everytime I try to run it in QGIS 2.16.1 on Windows OS. Here is the full error description:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/GenotypePhenotype/.qgis2/python/plugins\BufferByPercentage\bufferbypercentage.py", line 184, in run
    self.target_factor, self.segments)
  File "C:/Users/GenPhen/.qgis2/python/plugins\BufferByPercentage\bufferbypercentage.py", line 57, in find_buffer_length
    area_unscaled, target_factor)
  File "C:/Users/Genotype-Phenotype/.qgis2/python/plugins\BufferByPercentage\bufferbypercentage.py", line 78, in secant
    oldf, f = func(oldx, *args), func(x, *args)
  File "C:/Users/Genotype-Phenotype/.qgis2/python/plugins\BufferByPercentage\bufferbypercentage.py", line 67, in calculateError
    print area_scaled
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.16.1-Nødebo Nødebo, 8545b3b 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS21~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing
C:/Users/Genotype-Phenotype/.qgis2/python/plugins\LecoS
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS21~1.1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/Genotype-Phenotype/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/Genotype-Phenotype/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS21~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS21~1.1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/Genotype-Phenotype/.qgis2//python
```

Comment: Mac OS doesn't refer to file paths with **C:/PROGRA~1/** ... are you running under Parallels?

Comment: It is a windows OS. Edited.

Comment: what version of the plugin are you using? (You can find this in plugin manager). If it shows there is a newer version available, have you tried upgrading the plugin? Going by the changelog, you need to be using version 0.2.4 or later of the plugin.

Comment: @agGIS: It seems this is related to some spurious `print` commands. They're [removed now](https://github.com/jdugge/BufferByPercentage/commit/e98baa93ece148eb4de7f3a56b1a1b2abf58aca3) and a new version (0.2.4.2) has been made available in the repository. Could you test whether upgrading the plugin to 0.2.4.2 fixes the problem?